# Iterating over a bool list/array returns all false

Tags: c#, list, winforms, boolean

I'm creating  this  windows forms c# app where i can load images from folder, choose few of them by clicking on their image and then copy them to another  folder. So far everything seemed good but now i stumbled upon problem. I have 10 bools which are representing each image status ( selected or not selected).

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public bool selected1 = false;
    public bool selected2 = false;
    public bool selected3 = false;
    public bool selected4 = false;
    public bool selected5 = false;
    public bool selected6 = false;
    public bool selected7 = false;
    public bool selected8 = false;
    public bool selected9 = false;
    public bool selected10 = false;
```

these are those bools.
Next i put them in the list ( i tested array too )

```
private List<bool> selectedBools = new List<bool>();
```

And then i assign bools to the list in the Public Form1():

```
 selectedBools = new List<bool> { selected1, selected2, selected3, selected4, selected5, selected6, selected7, selected8, selected9, selected10 };
```

Each image status is controlled by this piece of code ( every picturebox_click has the same code with changed numbers )

```
 private void pictureBox2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (selected1 == false)
        {

            pctBox1.Image = null;


            selected1 = true;
            pctBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (selected1 == true)
        {
            selected1 = false;
            pctBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            try
            {
                pctBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filePaths[0 + Page * 10]); // refresh image
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }

    }
```

Then when i press to change "Page" ( which just moves every image by 10 ) i set all of the bools again to false.
The problem is when i want to "upload" those images to the folder ( just copy selected there):

```
 private void UploadAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(selected1.ToString() + selected2 + selected3 + selected4 + selected5 + selected6 + selected7 + selected8 + selected9 + selected10);
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure?", "Upload all", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
       
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
          
            List<int> selectedBooleansIndexes = new List<int>();
            int i = 10;
            foreach (bool selected in selectedBools)
            {
                
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine(selected);

                Console.WriteLine(selectedBools[i]);
                if (selected == true)
                {
                    int index = selectedBools.FindIndex(a => a = true);
                    selectedBooleansIndexes.Add(index);
                    Console.WriteLine(selectedBooleansIndexes.Count);
                  }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(selected1.ToString() + selected2 + selected3 + selected4 + selected5 + selected6 + selected7 + selected8 + selected9 + selected10);
                    MessageBox.Show(this, selectedBooleansIndexes.Count.ToString(), "siur");
                }
```

When I select some images, their select bool changes to true. So i wanted to grab those that are set to true and get their indexes so later i can you those indexes when copying files. Problem is when i run if (selected == true ) all of them seem to be false and nothing happens. I checked that by manually typing out in console status of every bool and when i do that, it works as intended. So my problem is, when i use foreach loop, every bool status is false even though it isn't ( i checked it many times because i thought that something overrides them in diffrent place in code). Maybe i'm missing something but it's strange.

Comment: Guessing,... the values in `List<bool>` will not change if you change the variables. That's the difference between value and reference types. Looks like you update your `selected2 ...` variables only but then you iterate over the list which was never updated. I'd suggest to take a debugger instead of console.log "debugging". This will give you a much better understanding what happens.

Comment: Build a class object that stores the reference to a PictureBox, to the path / Uri of the Image it shows, its Selected status, the custom Colors to set when the Image is selected / unselected. Let the class subscribe to the Click event of your PictureBoxes. Add a new instance of this class to a `List<class>` for every image you load. -- In the end, select the objects in the list `Where()` the `Selected` Property is `true`. All the details needed are stored in the class objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify your code in order to explain:

```
bool b1 = false;
bool b2 = false
```

Up to here, everything is as expected by you. b1 and b2 are both `false`.

```
List<bool> l = new List<bool>(){b1, b2};
```

You now have a list with **copies** of `b1` and `b2`. That is because booleans are value types.

What does that mean? If you change `b1`, `[0]` will **not** change with it. If you change `l[0]`, `b1` will **not** change with it. Same for `b2` and `l[1]`. They are totally independent.

Let's move to the larger problem now. You definitely don't want copies, so don't create them.

Instead of

```
public bool selected1 = false;
[...]
public bool selected10 = false;
```

use the list **only** and access the entries via their index. Think of an application which has 1000 images instead of 10. You would not want to declare 1000 variables, would you?

Let's create a list of 10 booleans, initialized with `false` (because that's their default value):

```
List<bool> selected = new List<bool>(new bool[10]);
```

Let's also put all your picture boxes into a list:

```
List<PictureBox> pictures = List<PictureBox>{pctBox1, ... pctBox10};
```

Whenever `pctBox1` changes, `pictures[0]` will change with it. It is **not a copy**. This will work, because PictureBox is a reference type instead of a value type.

That way, you can define a single method which does all the things:

```
private void DoSomething(int index)
{
        if (selected[index] == false)
        {    
            pictures[index].Image = null;        
            selected[index] = true;
            pictures[index].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else  // DONE: if (selected[index] == true) is unnecessary, because true is the only option left
        {
            selected[index] = false;
            pictures[index].BackColor = Color.White;
            try
            {
                pictures[index].Image = Image.FromFile(filePaths[index + Page * 10]); // refresh image
            }
            catch { } // TODO: fix bad error handling
        }
 }
```

and every click event handler becomes as simple as

```
private void pictureBox2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething(0);  // change index only
}
```

We would typically further simplify the `DoSomething()` method.

```
private void DoSomething(int index)
{   
    selected[index] = !selected[index];  // Flip the value
    pictures[index].BackColor = selected[index]?Color.White:Color.Red;  // Choose the back color
    pictures[index].Image = null;  // Reset always, since it doesn't really matter
    if (selected[index])
    {
        try
        {
            pictures[index].Image = Image.FromFile(filePaths[index + Page * 10]); // refresh image
        }
        catch {} // TODO: still fix bad error handling
    }
}
```

I think that's enough for today. One would probably not create 10 picture boxes manually either, but have them be created in a loop.

Comment: Thanks! Worked really well, thank you for explaining everything dude <3